# Indent values in a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel spreadsheet I use the below VBA codes to get a `UserForm` with a `ComboBox` using the values from `Sheet1`:

List for **ComboBox1** on spreadsheet:

```
         A               B             C
1    Q1
2      January
3      February
4      March
5    Q2
6      April
7      May
8      June
```

VBA code to **call** UserForm1 (connected to a button on the spreadsheet):

```
Sub Test()
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
End Sub
```

VBA code of **UserForm1**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8").Value
End Sub
```

In the end the **UserForm1** looks like this:

[image]

All this works fine so far.

---

As you can see in my original list in the spreadsheet the `month` below the `quarters` are **indented**. 
 Is it possible to also indent the values in the **ComboBox1** of the **UserForm1**?

Comment: How about adding some spaces before, where needed? You can use `Trim()` later to remove them from the value of the ComboBox.

Comment: I assume the issue is that you **are** adding spaces in the source data but Excel is removing them automatically, correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg no Excel keeps the spaces

Comment: @Pᴇʜ -  actually i just confirmed the same thing...  I don't understand the problem then...

Comment: @ashleedawg The issue might be when using `ComboBox1.Value` in combination with the spaces it also has the spaces in its value and you would need to use `Trim$(ComboBox1.Value)` to get rid of them.

Comment: @ashleeedawg The idea with the space works for the display of the values in the ComboBox. However, since I insert the value that is selected in the ComboBox later in my sheet to use it as a filter I need to get rid of the space as you said. I tried to put the Trim& function in my formula but could not make it work so far.

Comment: Another idea - You can have more then one column in a combo box. Add in a second column and position as needed

Comment: @Michi *"could not make it work so far."* does not describe what you did or what went wrong or which errors you got. Update your question and show how you tried it and which error you got or what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @Peh: I tried it again and could make it work. See edits from the answer of Larsg432.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the issue by `putting a space before the values` in the sheet and then go with one of the following VBA options:

---

**Option 1:**

VBA for **ComboBox**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8").Value
End Sub
```

VBA to insert the selected values without the space into the **spreadsheet**: 
*(In order to use them further in the spreadsheet)*

```
Sub ComboBox1_Insert_Value()
Sheet1.Range("E1").Value = Trim(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

---

**Option 2:**

VBA for **ComboBox**: 
Loop through the ranges and check if the horizontal orientation is set to right. If so then you could add a space in front of the value of the cell.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
For Each cell In Range("A1:A8")
    If cell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem "  " & cell.Value
    Else
        ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

VBA to insert the selected values without the space into the **spreadsheet**: 
*(In order to use them further in the spreadsheet)*

```
Sub ComboBox1_Insert_Value()
Sheet1.Range("E1").Value = Trim(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Works very well.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Have a nice day. And thanks for editing @PEH

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment you could use multiple columns in your combobox and adjust the column widths as desired. e.g.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Debug.Print ComboBox1.Value
    With ComboBox1
        If .Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Text = Split(.Value, "-")(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Quarter As String
    Dim c

    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "0;20;40"
        For Each c In rng
            If c.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Or c.IndentLevel > 0 Or Len(c.Value2) > Len(LTrim(c.Value2)) Then
                .AddItem Quarter & "-" & c.Value2
                .Column(2, .ListCount - 1) = c.Value2
            Else
                Quarter = c.Value2
                .AddItem vbNullString
                .Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = Quarter
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

This works using three columns all together. The first one is hidden from the end user and is used as line ID value (combination of `Quarter` and `month`), the second column holds the `Quarter` value and the third holds the `month` value

Produces:

[image: Example]

Comment: Well in this case the `ComboBox1.Value` is empty when a month was selected and you try reading it.

Comment: @Peh Thanks - have updated to solve that. Also, added in a line id column which is hidden from the end user